# С# free control (UWP/WPF/Winforms) similar to mxGraph (draw.io)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, uwp, controls

**Is there anything like js lib mxGraph (https://www.draw.io/) availabe for desktop c# apps?** (Any GUI)

- I know draw.io using mxGraph, which also has Java version, but i didn't find .net implementation. *(in fact it has C# renderer, which renders graph to System.Drawing.Image without any interaction support)*
- I know there is graphviz and graphsharp, but there is no tutorial/user manual like mxGraph has.
- I know there is telerik, syncfusion etc controls, but they are paid.

The thing is I need a diagraming tool for my app, and I don't want to invent a wheel. 
But it seems like either I stick with undocumented graphsharp or create an Electron app (low perfomace, high memory usage)

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: nah, seems like c shap community is not big enough and still depends much on Microsoft. So there is small number of 3rd party controls((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help https://github.com/prepare/opendiagram .

Open Diagram is a .net diagramming component library for the .Net framework winforms environment.

I use a product that uses this, personally I have no experience in developing with it.

Comment: This is brilliant, I don't know how I miss this. It's a winforms though, but it would be at least great starting point